# Button Disabled after using Time Function inside settimeout

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Daily Checkin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
      <ul>
      <li>
          1. 3Hub<button id="done11" class="btn">
            <a id="claim11" class="link" href="https://3hub.io" target="_blank">Claim</a>
            </button>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </div>

  <footer>&copy;Developed By Srijan</footer>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </html>
```

Javascript Code :

```
var links11 = document.getElementById("claim11");
var done11 = document.getElementById("done11");

links11.addEventListener("click", function(){
    done11.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    done11.innerText = "Claimed" ;

localStorage.setItem("color",done11.style.backgroundColor);
localStorage.setItem("name",done11.innerText);

})

var storedcolor = localStorage.getItem("color");
var storedvalue = localStorage.getItem("name");
if(storedcolor){
    done11.style.backgroundColor = storedcolor;
    done11.innerText = storedvalue;
}
function nday(){
    var now = new Date();
    now.setUTCHours(4,30,0)
    // console.log(now)
    return now
}

var see = nday();
console.log(see);

    setTimeout(function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("color");
    localStorage.removeItem("name");
    done11.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    done11.innerText = "Claim";
},nday());
```

now problem is In The Above Code When I am Using nday() inside settimeout my button gets unclcickable and greyed out but instead of it if i am using numbers as time its working.

i dont know why this is happening Already tried using nday or nday() both still same outputjavas

Comment: looking at the `nday` function - if you returned that date as a number, the timeout wouldn't trigger for 54 years ... settimeout doesn't take a date as the time to trigger, it takes a number of milliseconds - is your intent to trigger AT 4:30, or in 4 hours 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the nday() stands for, but I guess you are doing a count down for button to be enable, if that case, try the code below:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    localStorage.removeItem("color");
    localStorage.removeItem("name");
    done11.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    done11.innerText = "Claim";
}, Date.now() - see); 
// You have already initialised a variable see with nday() value, might as well reuse it here
```